# How to block specific UDP packet outgoing from machine using iptables

Tags: iptables, udp, packet

I want to block specific UDP packet OUTGOING from my machine using iptables. Packet has a string in "hex in RAW"(?) i want to check packet by it.

Like: If UDP packet hex RAW match "test_text" - block it.

//EDIT:
i have something like this

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp -m multiport --sports 8000 -m string --algo bm --string "test" -j DROP
```

but it gives error

> iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a "string" match netfilter extension, that might or might not be compiled in/available as a module on your system.

Do not forget that such things can inherently have a serious performance impact, especially if more packets than necessary are subjected to that match.